# AngularJs routing white screen while loading page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

A have a web application (AngularJS 1.5.6) that changes the screen content every x seconds. The screen is white for 1-2 seconds after the change, because there is a lot of data processing behind, Http get calls, etc.

The app is using ui.router to change the page content. The Controller is pretty big and is using a lot of other services and directive components.

I tried to move the content from a app.factory component (the main factor that produces this delay) to a app.provider and use it in $stateProvider.resolve block but i'm getting a lot of errors.

Is there another option to this problem?

If not, how should I refactor my code? Do you have an example?

Thank You!

Comment: can you show your config (states)?

Comment: $stateProvider
        .state("page", {
            url: "/:Id/:Type",
            template: pageTemplate,
            controller: "contentCtrl"
        })

Comment: well, 1-2 seconds is a lot, but have you tried resolving the data by adding `resolve:{someData:function($http){return $http.get(...)}}`? And then Injecting that data/Promise into the controller